# Data not being updated in sqlalchemy session

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a problem of updating an instance in sqlalchemy.
The instance attributes change after I modify them before the commit, but after I commit them they are back to the previous values. The session.is_modified(instance) too returns a False even after the data is updated.

Here is the code

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session


class Backend(object):
"""
"""
def __init__(self):

    self._engine = create_engine("mysql://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}?charset=utf8".format(DATABASE_CONFIGS.get('master').get('USER'),
                                                                  DATABASE_CONFIGS.get('master').get('PASSWORD'),
                                                                  DATABASE_CONFIGS.get('master').get('HOST'),
                                                                  DATABASE_CONFIGS.get('master').get('DB_NAME')),
                                 pool_recycle=3600,
                                 pool_size= POOL_SIZE,
                                 pool_timeout=1,
                                 echo=False,
                                 convert_unicode=True,
                                 encoding='utf-8')


def get_session(self):
    self._session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=self._engine))
    return self._session


class A():
    attribute_meta = Column(JSONField(), nullable=True)
```

This is how the code is run:

```
def foo():
    backend = Backend()
    session = backend.get_session()
    a = session.query(A).first()
    a.attribute_meta = {'boo':'foo'}
    session.add(a)
    print("data before commit", a.attribute_meta)
    print("is session modified", session.is_modified(a))
    print("data after commit", a.attribute_meta)
    session.commit()
    session.close()
```

is session modified returns False
data before commit returns the modifed instance with appropriate data
data after commit returns the instance with its original value i.e. not modified

If I run the same code via shell, it works fine.
There are no post signals to the model that would alter the data too.

Turned on the echo=True but all is shows is just a select command that being fired in the db.

Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The attribute I was trying to change was a JSON field and sqlalchemy doesn't check changes in a JSON field.
That was the reason why those changes were there in the instance before a commit but the perished after it.
The solution is to forcibly make the instance dirty i.e. make sqlalchemy purposefully check that attribute changes.

This is the code change -

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import flag_modified

flag_modified(bag, 'affiliate_meta')  # Just because sqlalchemy doesnt track json field changes, check it before committing the session
```

Comment: Your question lacks a [mcve]. You have not included the definition of `JSONField`, and `a.attribute_meta = {'boo':'foo'}` would actually work, depending on the definition of `JSONField`. SQLA does not track changes to the **value itself** by default (there are proper ways to track mutations, though). If you assign a **new value** entirely (as you do) it works, if using the usual JSON types.

Comment: I don't know what you didn't understand to make it a minimal, complete and verifiable example as I'd included the model definitions stating JSONField.
On the other hand, it did work if I tried it via shell(most probably you would have done the same), did mention that too but it didn't work while running in the project.
can you explain what you think should be explained as a 'minimal, complete and verifiable example'?